# Is it possible to index a field’s string length in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible for me to add a field’s length to an index in MongoDB?

I would like to be able to filter query results by a field’s length, for which `$strLenCP` works well but I’m wondering if there’s a way for me to index that to ensure the most efficient query.

To filter the length in a query I would use something like:

```
Model.find({
    "$expr": { 
        "$eq": [
            { "$strLenCP": "$name" }, lengthQuery
            // lengthQuery being the desired length
        ]
    }
})
```

But I’m not sure if I can use a similar method in index creation. It would theoretically look something like:

```
Model.createIndex({ name: 1, length: { “$strLenCP”: “$name” } })
```

I’m just wondering if this is valid and possible.

My only other workaround would be to add an additional field that stores the length of `name` as a number to the collection and index this field but I’m wondering if I can avoid doing that and increasing storage.

Comment: No, not directly as you're hoping. You'd have to pursue the workaround that you described

Comment: @user20042973 thanks, that’s a shame but I assumed so.